# R package googlesheets4 returns Client error: (429) RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED when reading a public sheet

Tags: r, googlesheets4

```
library(googlesheets4)

url_rls <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/d/17eJ05pg6fkzKlwwiWn0ztdMvzBX9pGx3q6w7h3_vJw4/"
gs4_deauth()
read_sheet(url_rls)
```

Returns this error sometimes, but not always.  Do I need to login just to read a public file?

```
Error: Client error: (429) RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED
  * Either out of resource quota or reaching rate limiting. The client should look for google.rpc.QuotaFailure error detail for more information.
  * Quota exceeded for quota group 'ReadGroup' and limit 'Read requests per 100 seconds' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:603366585132'.
```

Comment: More details at https://github.com/r-lib/gargle/issues/146#issuecomment-645449077. In short, I think that you do need to log in to read a public file via googlesheets4 -- but there are workarounds for the error that you're getting.

Comment: thanks! I've seen that post, but I ended up in a rabbithole of deprecated function and kind of gave up.  

I ended up moving my cronjob 1 minute earlier, so now I'm reading the sheet before everyone else.. :)

Answer (score 1):

When I get this error message to either knit my RMD or to process a graphic I have a workaround (because I do not know how to do the API fix).

Normally I input on the console gs4_auth() & to knit I input rmarkdown::render("file.Rmd").

And that error does not appear anymore and I´m able to render everything

Comment: Sometimes I have to do it 2 or 3 times for it to work, but it works every time